# Visual studio mdf database structure modified then lost after publish

Tags: c#, database, clickonce

Service-based database is new to me. I would like to create a simple database application with:

- Service-based database -> Dataset (mdf)
- LINQ to SQL (L2S) Classes

This application will be installed on a lot of individual machines every instances has it's own mdf database.
Installation is done by **Clickonce**.

**My problem is:**

1. I publish my application and install it on user machines
2. Users put some data into the database
3. Turns out that we need another table or column
4. Publish the application again with the extended database and install on user machines
5. User starts with a new database and original data lost!

(If I am not modifying the database structure than all data is in the database after next Clickone update)

**Questions:**

If I made only alter table- or add table- like modifications is there any way to preserve data during the next Clickonce update?

Thank you in advance!
Dave

Comment: Found a hint for the question
[link]http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/24ada8b9-7a27-4e86-a16a-d6a620d216a0/clickonce-deployment-of-access-database

Comment: Found another hint: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/4671a906-0755-438b-80a2-283a0eb5f392/clickonce-deployment-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.
If you modify your database model in visual studio Clickonce will automatically recreate all tables after installation (newly published application with modified tables).
Clickonce save the old database to a specified location:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed && ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory != null)
     string preDatabase = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory,@".pre\sampledatabase.mdf"));
```

This .pre directory is created by Clickonce. You always check if this file is exist or not. If it is exist you have to copy data from old tables to new tables **OR you will loose all data from old tables!**

How to copy data from one database to another very similar database? My answer is the following: copy all table to another table with SqlBulkCopy.

```
        // Create source connection
        using (
            var source =
                new SqlConnection(
                    String.Format(
                        @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;",
                        preDatabase)))
        {
            source.Open();
            // Create destination connection
            using (var destination = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.mdcdbConnectionString))
            {
                destination.Open();
                DataTable dt = source.GetSchema("Tables");
                foreach (string tablename in from DataRow row in dt.Rows select (string) row[2])
                {
                    App.Logger.LogText(String.Format("Copying table {0}", tablename));

                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("TRUNCATE TABLE {0}", tablename), destination))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //App.Logger.LogText(String.Format("truncate table {0}", tablename));
                    }
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tablename), source))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            var bulkData = new SqlBulkCopy(destination)
                                {
                                    DestinationTableName = tablename
                                };
                            // Set destination table name
                            bulkData.WriteToServer(reader);
                            // Close objects
                            bulkData.Close();
                            //App.Logger.LogText(String.Format("Copy success {0}", tablename));
                        }
                    }
                }
                destination.Close();
            }
            source.Close();
        }
```

Wish you good coding!
Dave